# Eclipse throws error when using less than(<) symbol

Tags: java, syntax-error

Eclipse throws a Syntax error when i use the less than symbol.

The line that throws the error is as follows:

`for (Iterator localIterator = linePanels.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); i < pane.getComponentCount());`

I can't for the life of me figure out why it is throwing the error, it compiled fine before and runs fine, I havn't changed any code at all. I just opened it back up in eclipse and it throws the error.
If you need any more info just ask.
Edit:
The method where i get the error is as follows:

```
public void deselectAll()
{
JLayeredPane pane;
int i;
for (Iterator localIterator = linePanels.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); i < pane.getComponentCount())
 {
   pane = (JLayeredPane)localIterator.next();
   i = 0; continue;
   Component c = pane.getComponent(i);
   if ((c instanceof SimpleUIElement)) {
     ((SimpleUIElement)c).setSelected(false);
   }
   i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is `i` declared.?

Comment: And what is the error says?

Comment: Your loop isn't gonna do anything because you call continue every time. It will just skip everything you do, why did you add a useless continue there?

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what youre trying to do in the third part of your for statement, but the third part just takes an expression, and you entered a condition. is what you wanted to type this? :

```
for (Iterator localIterator = linePanels.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext() && i < pane.getComponentCount(););
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put a condition in third part of of for loop, otherwise it will give compile time error. above for statement will not  compile

Answer (score 0):

Compiling this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; 2 < 3){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

gives me the following error:

```
Main.java:13: error: not a statement
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; 2 < 3){
                            ^
```

So it's all because your 'for loop' structure is wrong. You have to change it to:

```
 for (Iterator localIterator = linePanels.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext() && i < pane.getComponentCount(););
```

Note that I just compiled it with a java compiler, an IDE doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: I tried changing the for loop to what you said and I get another error. `localIterator cannot be resolved`

Comment: @Ricky import java.util.Iterator;